# How to calculate the final price of each product within a List<T>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

### The goal

Calculate the final price of each product within a `List<T>` of C#.

### The problem

I need to calculate `price * quantity` of a simple product and return the result to the view.

Look this syntax:

```
var productPrice = productsPrices.Find(x => x.productId == 1); 
productPrice.finalProductPrice = 
    (productPrice.promotionalProductPrice != 0 ? 
        productPrice.promotionalProductPrice : 
        productPrice.originalProductPrice) 
    * sessionProducts.Find(x => x.id == 1).quantity;
```

Just before of code fragment passed above, there is a string that stores the ids of the products, see:

```
string ids = string.Join(", ", sessionProducts.Select(x => x.id));
```

And I think that I need it to set a value to `finalProductPrice` of each product of my `productsPrices` list, but I don't know how I can perform this.

### What I thought about this subject:

I had thought that I could use something like this:

```
productsPrices.Find(x => x.productId == productsPrices.Contains(ids))
    .finalProductPrice = 
    (productsPrices.Find(x => productsPrices.Contains(ids))
        .promotionalProductPrice != 0 ?
    productsPrices.Find(x => productsPrices.Contains(ids))
        .promotionalProductPrice : 
    productsPrices.Find(x => productsPrices.Contains(ids))
        .originalProductPrice) *
    sessionProducts.Find(x => x.id == 1).quantity;
```

But, of course, no success — `.Contains()` doesn't work with strings.

### My *real* question

How can I define the right `finalProductPrice` for each product that my `productsPrices` list has? How can I pass each id within `string ids [...]` to `x.productId == something`?

Hints will be welcome (E.g. *don't use `.Find()`, use `.Select()` instead!)*

### Spotlight code

Follow my `ActionResult` that sends all the necessary information to my view:

**Compare.cs**:

```
public ActionResult Compare()
{
    List<getMarkets_Result> markets = Markets.Build();

    SessionStore sessionStore = new SessionStore();
    List<getSpecificProductToShoppingList_Result> sessionProducts = 
        sessionStore.Get("ProductsSummary", "generic");

    string ids = string.Join(", ", sessionProducts.Select(x => x.id));
    List<getProductsPrices_Result> productsPrices = Products.PricesList(ids);

    ListComparisonViewModel listComparisonViewModel = 
       new ListComparisonViewModel
    {
        Markets = markets,
        SessionProducts = sessionStore.Get("ProductsSummary", "generic"),
        ProductsPrices = productsPrices
    };

    return View(listComparisonViewModel);
}
```

If necessary, the context of my `productsPrice` list:

```
public partial class getProductsPrices_Result
{
    public decimal originalProductPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal promotionalProductPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal finalProductPrice { get; set; }
    public string productName { get; set; }
    public string marketName { get; set; }
    public int productId { get; set; }
    public int marketId { get; set; }
}
```

And I made a model called **Products(.cs)** to perform the logic behind of the products. The first (and single) method that this model has is `CalculateFinalPrice()`:

```
public decimal CalculateProductPriceByQuantity(decimal price, int quantity)
{
    return price * quantity;
}
```

Comment: Creating a new property within your class and do the calculation in the get isn't enough for you?

Comment: Not enough for a full answer but you should look in to refactoring the first code block to somthing like `var productPrice = productsPrices.Find(x => x.productId == 1); productPrice.finalProductPrice = 
    (productPrice.promotionalProductPrice != 0 ?
    productPrice.promotionalProductPrice : 
    productPrice.originalProductPrice) *
    sessionProducts.Find(x => x.id == 1).quantity;`

Comment: @RandRandom Isn't enough — `getProductsPrices_Result` doesn't know `quantity` — `quantity` is a property provided by `Session`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Oh, thanks. I updated the main post. But as you said, your answer isn't enough to solve my problem.

Comment: Do you need the final price per product or the total price for the "cart"?

Comment: @RacielR. Per product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should conciser creating a model that represents your data in a way that will make your business problem easier to solve. In other words, make the code work to solve you solution.

Firstly the product should not know about the quantity. Assuming this works like a cart, the product should only know about itself. So the implementation of `finalProductPrice` should be much easier:

```
public decimal finalProductPrice 
{
    get 
    {
        return (promotionalProductPrice != 0 ? 
            promotionalProductPrice : 
            originalProductPrice);
    }
}
```

When working with your products, create a class and contain them in that to calculate the quality and total price:

```
public class ProductCollection
{
    public IEnumerable<getProductsPrices_Result> Products { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get { return Products.Count; } }
    public decimal TotalPrice 
    {
        get
        {
            return Products.Sum(p => p.finalProductPrice );
        }
    }
    public ProductCollection(IEnumerable<getProductsPrices_Result> products)
    {
        this.Products = products;
    }
}
```

Now your viewmodel can look something like this:

```
ListComparisonViewModel
{
    Markets = markets,
    Products = new ProductCollection(sessionStore.Get("ProductsSummary", "generic"))
};
```

One important note I would like to make here is this helps to reduce your session access surface area. Session can be "accessed by anyone" and thus can become discombobulated and cause lots of issues down the road. In almost all scenarios fewer hands in the session cookie jar the better. (fewer keys as well as fewer class types and instances)

Comment: What is the alternative to Session?

Comment: You can either wrap session with a class exposing strongly typed properties, or if you don't use session at all the client posts all data necessary to perform any given action. But this is an whole discussion in of itself.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a lot of issues here. Firstly, your properties should be PascalCase, not camelCase. Secondly, your class is poorly named. `getProductsPrices_Result` shouldn't be prefixed with a verb, and it should be PascalCase with no underscores.

Aside from that, you have a lot of redundant code. The `FinalProductPrice` doesn't sound like an appropriate property for a `Product` type.

To answer the question about getting a collection of products that match a collection of ids, you can use LINQ:

```
string[] ids = ...;
List<Product> products = ...;

List<Product> matchingProducts = 
    products.Where(p => ids.Any(i => i == p.Id)).ToList();
```

Comment: I get the feeling a lot of the problems you've pointed out are because of the code generation of the db. `getProductsPrices_Result` sounds like a stored proc result, and `FinalProductPrice` is probably a db column. Not idea, and should not see the controller code, but not really a big deal either.

Comment: Can you tell me a better way to pass to the view the `FinalProductPrice`? And about the nomenclature: I'm using Entity Framework and all those properties and class names are generated by it — my naming pattern of database is `camelCase`.

Comment: @Jay You're right in your point of view *(thanks for the help!)*. But, actually, `FinalProductPrice` isn't a database column — it is a property implemented by C# with a partial/extended class.

Comment: It sounds like you should be using another type or service to be calculating the final result. If you only need it for display purposes, then you should consider a product view model. You could also consider Entity Framework code first if you wish to avoid code generation. You shouldn't let the persistence technology dictate your domain model.

Comment: Can you give me more details about the view model? (I'm not asking for *ready-to-go code*, just a more detailed and consistently explanation)

Comment: Your code isn't the easiest to follow, it's not using descriptive and meaningful phrases. For example, why is the logic to calculate the product prices a static method on a type called 'Products'? As Jay also mentioned, your controllers should be thin, and persistence ignorant. Instead of performing data access logic directly in the controller, one consideration may be to use the repository and unit of work patterns. It's difficult to provide specific code examples as they are quite broad concepts, but I hope your original question regarding list querying is answered.

Answer (score 0):

question is a bit fuzzy but looks like you may be looking for something like following

```
var res = (from p in products
           from s in sessionproducts
           where p.id == s.id
           select new Product() { id = p.id, finalprice = s.qty * (p.promoprice > 0 ? p.promoprice : p.price) })
           .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

- I would double check your class design.
- I would make promotionalPrice
  nullable, what if you need price = 0 for a promotion?
- Consider making this an extension method for the collection of products references in session.

With what I have at hand:

```
foreach(var product in sessionProducts){        
    var productPrice == productPrices.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.ProductId == product.id);
    var price = 0;
    if (productPrice != null)
       price = productPrice.promotionalPrice == 0 ? productPrice.originalPrice : productPrice.promotionalPrice;

    product.finalPrice = product.Qty * price;
}
```

Comment: `foreach` can be used in this case? I mean, it is a good way to do what I want?

Comment: Be careful of closure over `product.id`, I am not 100% sure if you will run in to any issues or not but I would make a local variable to be safe when working with lambadas.